# Navigation drawer not opening from cutom menu button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on an Android App, I have a navigation drawer over there. Since the navigation drawer toolbar can't be transparent, and the ending three dots button icon can't be changed, I opted for hiding that toolbar, and show my custom layout. It will give me all the functionality what ever is needed.

But the problem I'm facing right now is, once the activity starts, if I click the custom menu button it doesn't open. Once I drag it and open, after that whenever I click the menu button it opens the navigation drawer.

What might i be missing? This is what I'm doing, while debugging its even coming to the else part, but doesn't open.

In BaseActivity:

```
drawer                  = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


ivLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    });
```

In any of the child activity:

```
 toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Please help..

Comment: It sounds like you're setting `ivLeft`'s `OnClickListener` in one of the `DrawerListener` methods. Where are you calling the code block you've posted, exactly?

Comment: Actually I've Baseactivity and child activity functionalaity.

This code is in my BaseActivity so that all the child activity can use the same functionaity.

And ivLeft is public too.

Comment: We'll need to see more of the surrounding, relevant code, please.

Comment: Please check the edit in the actual thread.

Comment: Is the `NavigationView` your drawer `View`? If so, why are you setting its visibility to `GONE`?

Comment: In fact, after a quick glance at `DrawerLayout`'s source, I believe that explains the behavior you're describing. Try removing the `navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line.

Comment: So that it doesn't show up in the child activity. I don't want the screen to show the navigation drawer top toolbar too.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks a lot. I didn't guess that might create that problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Yeah, that's interesting behavior I've never observed before. I'll post an answer with the explanation here in a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is the fact that you're setting the drawer `View`'s visibility to `GONE`. The direct cause of the odd behavior you describe, though, is due to how `DrawerLayout` and one of its helper classes update the child `View`s when the drawer state changes.

The `OnClickListener` you set to open and close the drawer was working as it should. It just didn't appear to be, since the drawer `View` was `GONE`. When you manually opened the drawer by dragging, however, the `ViewDragHelper` that `DrawerLayout` uses was firing a callback method that explicitly sets the drawer to `VISIBLE`. This callback is not fired when the drawer is opened programmatically - that is, with the `openDrawer()` method - which explains why the drawer didn't show just by clicking your custom toggle button. After you had dragged the drawer open once, the drawer `View` was visible, and the toggle would then work as expected.

The drawer `View` is in its closed state by default, so you don't need to hide it, and you can just remove the `navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line.